# How to get the last user input in Rasa

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I can fetch the last user-inputted data from RASA chatbot using this method.

```
text = tracker.latest_message['text']
```

It's working perfectly in my case. Now I want to fetch the text of a button pressed by the user. For example, if the user presses the allion button, I want my `text` variable to hold as `text = "allion"`.

[image]

**Is there any preferable solution?**

Answer (score 1):

The same way, you can get the string "allion" on click of the button, if you have sent the `payload: allion` in the button data.

```
buttons:
- title: allion
  payload: allion
```

Now when the user click the button, the Payload will be sent as user message. You can fetch that from `tracker.events` in your `actions.py`. All you need to add is, a check for what string has been sent.

```
for event in (list(reversed(tracker.events)))[:5]: # latest 5 messages
    if event.get("event") == "user": # check if the sent by user or bot
        event.get("text") # check here what button string is received, if allion or premio or corolla or axio or prius
```